# UNIX command to sort the file by the following words, from major sort key to minor sort key: word 3, word 1, word 4

Tags: bash, unix, sorting

Need help with the UNIX command below to sort the file  by the following words, from major sort key to minor sort key: word 3, word 1, word 4. (words are separated by white spaces)

sort -t  -k3 -k1 -k4 > newfile.txt 
doesnt work

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is, get rid of the `-t` or specify `-t" "` or similar to specify a single character as your delimiter.

So:
    `sort -k3 -k1 -k4 in.txt > newfile.txt`

In detail...

*in.txt*

```
one two three four
the quick brown fox
jumps over the lazy dog
pun poo three poor
one two three four five
the elegant brown zebra
```

**bash cmd**

- You are sorting words, so just I'm showing how to specify the `-d` option for dictionary sort. You could use numeric sort with the `-g` option for other situations.
- You want whitespace - this is what sort uses by default. Otherwise you'd need to use `-t","` or similar.
- So the cmd is:

  `sort -k3,3d -k1,1d -k4,4d in.txt > newfile.txt`

*newfile.txt*

```
the quick brown fox
the elegant brown zebra
jumps over the lazy dog
one two three four
one two three four five
pun poo three poor
```

Comment: Thanx azhrei. That was fast.  Btw what does the d argument stands for ?